# How to find out the value of an inline constant while debugging a C program with GDB?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

Assume I have a compiled binary program, without debug symbols, with a source code similar to this in C:

```
char code[] = "1234";

if (atoi(code) == 4321) 
{
    puts("Right");
} 
else 
{
    puts("Wrong");
}
```

I debug the program with GDB.

Is there a way to find out the value of the integer defined as 4321 while I step through the program?

Comment: The inline constant should show up in the assembly. What did you see in the assembly?

Comment: the value of the integer defined as 4321 is 4321. It isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: Seemed fairly clear to me: given only compiler-generated machine code from this C source, can you find a `4321` in it somewhere?  I think it's implied you don't have the C source code either, but it's somewhat ambiguous about that.  With a stripped binary and the C source, it's certainly much easier to reverse engineer how the asm matches the source.

Comment: Reworked the question for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case no, e.g. `if (x < 10)` might get compiled to `cmp reg, 9` / `jle` for x86 (`x <= 9`).  Of course that's the same logic, but you can't recover whether the source used 9 or 10 from the immediate operand in the machine code.

Or constant-propagation or value-range analysis might have make the condition known-true at compile time so no immediate value appears in the asm at all.  e.g. a smart compiler that knows what `atoi` does could compile this C the same as `puts("Right");`.

---

In this *specific* case, it turns out GCC / clang don't bother looking for that optimization; `atoi` on compile-time-constant strings isn't something that normal programs do often so it's not worth the compile-time to make `strtol` a built-in function that would support constant-propagation.

**In this case the number does appear fairly obviously as an immediate constant, when GCC or clang compile it for x86-64 GNU/Linux** ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dcvcbn)), with your code (including the array declaration) inside a function.  Not as a global; that would make constant-propagation impossible.

This is the compiler's asm output; it hasn't had a round trip to machine code and back like you'd see inside `gdb` or other debuggers, but that would preserve everything except the symbol names.

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        push    rax                          # reserve 8 bytes for the local array
        mov     byte ptr [rsp + 4], 0        # Silly compiler, could have made the next instruction a qword store of a sign-extended 32-bit immediate to get the 0-termination for free.
        mov     dword ptr [rsp], 875770417   # the ASCII bytes of the "4321" array initializer
        mov     rdi, rsp
        xor     esi, esi
        mov     edx, 10
        call    strtol                      # atoi compiled to strtol(code, NULL, 10)
        cmp     eax, 4321                   # compare retval with immediate constant
        mov     eax, offset .L.str
        mov     edi, offset .L.str.1
        cmove   rdi, rax                    # select which string literal to pass to puts, based on FLAGS from the compare
        pop     rax                        # clear up the stack
        jmp     puts                    # TAILCALL

.section .rodata        # Godbolt filters directives, re-added this one.
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Right"

.L.str.1:
        .asciz  "Wrong"
```

---

Note that RISC ISAs sometimes have to construct constants using 2 instructions, or (common on 32-bit ARM), load them from memory with a PC-relative load.  So you won't always find constants as a single number.

Comment: Ok so just to clarify - in that case there is no way around analysing the assembly itself (if you are lucky and it's not optimized away by your particular compiler) to find out the value?